# Mangle rule for intercept DNS traffic form specific IP and redirect to another DNS server - openwrt

Tags: iptables, dns, routing, openwrt, nat

I have media box in my network  that hard coded to use specific DNS servers  like Google DNS. But I want force this device to use my own DNS servers instead of hard coded DNS. Only way I think this is possible to mangle the DNS request coming from that media box IP to DNAT to my DNS server IP. but I'm not quite sure how do I put rule with mentioning source port and source ip at the same time

I use openwrt router with openwrt 15.0 chaos calmer on it.

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --sport 53 -j DNAT --to-destination 192.168.1.153
```

Above query will do the job but it will mangle all the port 53 request. how can I specify this rule with IP address. or is there any other way to do it ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add `-d a.b.c.d` immediately after `tcp`, to restrict the rule to packets with destination address `a.b.c.d`.

And add `-s e.f.g.h` to also restrict by source address.

Comment: Thanks for the answer.. But it will mangle all the packet go to that 8.8.8.8 I only need to mangle packet from certain device

Answer (score 2):

I use

```
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p udp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT
iptables -t nat -A PREROUTING -p tcp --dport 53 -j REDIRECT
```

The redirect just redirects the requests to the router.